# objdump adjust vma offset in gnu Utilities

Tags: linux, unix, assembly, gnu, objdump

in The gnu Binary Utilities they say

```
objdump --adjust-vma=offset
```

> When dumping information, first add offset to all the section addresses. This
>   is useful if the section addresses do not correspond to the symbol table, which
>   can happen when putting sections at particular addresses when using a format
>   which can not represent section addresses, such as a.out.

i try to  understand it but i could not, so can any one explain to me what this option do? and what circumstance need this option in real life?

Comment: `offset` is a number you pass on the command line, which you use to fixup the output.  It's a number that's added to every address printed.  (Apparently `objdump` can't get that info from the file metadata for some formats).

Answer (score 1):

This option is mostly usefull when trying to disassemble DOS COM binaries.  A COM binary is a program image without any headers that is loaded to address 0x100 in some segment and executed by jumping to address 0x100.

`objdump` doesn't know this (after all, there is no way to detect that a file is a COM binary) and disassembles the binary as if it was loaded to address 0.  Passing `--adjust-vma=0x100` fixes this behaviour and makes `objdump` disassemble the binary as if it was loaded to 0x100 (which is what we want) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [fuz's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253262), another use case is for code which relocates itself (the archetypal example is the code in the IBM-PC [Master Boot Record](http://starman.vertcomp.com/asm/mbr/STDMBR.htm).) Depending whether the original code and hence the metadata was targeting the source *or* the destination address (either one is possible but not both at the same time), this option allows you to be presented the alternative dump.